# AngularJS - How to use datas from model to create graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can I use data (in angular 1.5) from the model to get the percentage for each class based on the number of students (count)?
With those datas I have to build a donught graph representing for each class the percentage of students compared to the total of school students..

```
"payload": {
    "Schools": [{
            "Sections": [{
                    "Name": "Class",
                    "Value": "2A"
                }, {
                    "Name": "Count",
                    "Value": 29
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "Sections": [{
                "Name": "Class",
                "Value": "3C",
            }, {
                "Name": "Count",
                "Value": 31

            }]
        }, {
            "Sections": [{
                "Name": "Class",
                "Value": "1B",
            }, {
                "Name": "Count",
                "Value": 27

            }]
        }
    ],
      "masterCategory": "School members",
      "totalStudents": 87
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of graph?

Comment: my problem is not the graph, my problem is the way to associate each data to the related value..

Comment: if this is not about graphs, please update your question title, as it's asking how to create a graph in angular. If you need to know how to go from a list of name/value pairs to a list of name/percentage pairs, this is not really an angular question.

Comment: In your Sections arrays, will the "Class" element always be first, and the "Count" element always second?

Comment: I'm sorry man, I'm new to the angular world.. For your second question the answer is yes! :)

Comment: With those datas I have to build a donught graph representing for each class the percentage of students compared to the total of school students..

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = {
    "Schools": [{
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "Class",
        "Value": "2A"
      }, {
        "Name": "Count",
        "Value": 29
      }]
    }, {
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "Class",
        "Value": "3C",
      }, {
        "Name": "Count",
        "Value": 31

      }]
    }, {
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "Class",
        "Value": "1B",
      }, {
        "Name": "Count",
        "Value": 27

      }]
    }],
    "masterCategory": "School members",
    "totalStudents": 87
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <h1 ng-repeat="x in records.Schools">{{x.Sections[0].Value}} = {{(x.Sections[1].Value/records.totalStudents)*100 | number : 0}}%</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is something I wanted! How can I get `x.Sections[0].Value` and `x.Sections[1].Value` inside the controller?^^

Comment: angular.forEach($scope.records.Schools, function(value, key) {
    console.log(value.Sections[0].Value + ': ' + value.Sections[1].Value + ': ' + $scope.records.totalStudents);
  });

Comment: With those datas I have to build a donught graph representing for each class the percentage of students compared to the total of school students..

Comment: Can u try below d3 js url meanwhile if you need I will try the same: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193

Comment: If you can.. It Will be great :D if you want try shaping it! :)